# Передать массив идентификаторов в хранимую процедуру (С#, MSSQL)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Вопрос в общем то заключается в следующем:
Есть список идентификаторов

```
List<int> Id = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Есть запрос на SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.Id in(1,2,3,4,5)
                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Нужно передать этот список, как параметр хранимой процедуры.

Конечно же есть ещё и экстремальные варианты типа превращение списка в строковую переменную, перечисляя элементы через запятую...

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(50) = '1,2,3,4,5'
EXEC('SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.Id in('+@Id+')')
```

Стоит ли заморачиваться?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если нужно хранимой процедуре передать список, это можно сделать с помощью xml, хотя самым оптимальным, на мой взгляд является применение User-defined table type. Для этого в MSSQL создается табличный тип (который может содержать один или несколько столбцов):

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[intTable] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int]
)
```

Создадим процедуру:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spProc
    @ids intTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM @ids)
END
```

При вызове хранимой процедуры из C# в качестве аргумента передается DataTable:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
foreach(var r in ids)
{
    data.Rows.Add(r);
}
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.spProc";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ids", SqlDbType.Structured);
        cmd.Parameters["@ids"].TypeName = "intTable";
        cmd.Parameters["@ids"].Value = data;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                    
    }
}
```

Подобным образом можно передать в хранимую процедуру и более сложную по структуре таблицу.

Comment: А что, если параметр не был передан, как сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию было WHERE Column  IN(/*ВСЕ ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ*/)

Comment: В таком случае в процедуру передаете пустую DataTable, а в самой процедуре меняете условие: 
`WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM @ids) OR (SELECT count(id) FROM @ids)=0`
Или процедуру переписываете так:
`CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spProc
    @ids intTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @ids)
  SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM @ids)
 ELSE
  SELECT * FROM table1
END`