# Передача массива в параметр SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Возможна ли передача массива в параметр SQL? Если я хочу массово удалить, или проставить статусы списку заказов, как это сделать?

```
List<int> vals = new List();
vals.Add(1);
vals.Add(2);

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconn_str))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn,
     "delete from order1 where id in (@ids)" ){
  cmd.Parametrs.AddWithValue("ids",vals);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
   }
```

Видел что библиотека кристала как-то это умеет делать, кто-нибудь передавал массив параметрически?

Comment: [Ассоциация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/691570/193999), [ещё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/791549/193999)

Comment: Спасибо, там в комментариях написано что делать, попробую.

Comment: Также можно создать временную таблицу (`#ids`) залить в неё данные при помощи _SqlBulkCopy_ и в запросе к ней приджойниться. Иногда это удобнее, т.к. не требует создания специального табличного типа.

Comment: Вспомнил статью: [Using Table-Valued Parameters
in SQL Server and .NET](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать простейший вариант:

```
var vals = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var ids = string.Join(",", vals);
var sql = $"delete from order1 where id in ({ids})";
```

Да, есть потенциальная опасность в виде sql-инъекций. Но если мы уверены во входных данных (а в данном случае это целые числа), то угрозы нет.

Например, Entity Framework генерирует аналогичный код (заменяя в строковых литералах `'` на `''`).

Проблема может быть только в том случае, когда массив очень велик.

Comment: Сервер MSSQL от таких "методов" захлебывается от нехватки памяти. Так делать нельзя с MSSQL. C некоторыми другими СУБД можно. MSSQL хеширует выборки и складирует, в надежде что она будет использована повторно. Я спрашиваю за параметрические выборки, потому что они ускоряют процесс, так я и сам напишу.